# Is it possible to call a sub method in a method?

Tags: typescript, methods

I have the following situation:

```
export class Test {

public Method_A() {
     console.log("Method_A");
  } 
}
```

And I do this in another file:

```
const test = new Test();

test.MethodA()
```

But I also need to do this:

```
const test = new Test();

test.MethodA().setSomething();
```

So how it is possible to create a method which is a sub of my Method_A()?

Comment: Well, you can have Method_A return an object with a setSomething property on it. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, but how did I do that? I tryed everything but I can not extend MethodA so that I can create a "setSomething" property.

Comment: You're not extending MethodA.  You're making MethodA return an object.  Eg. the body would be `{console.log("Method_A"); return myOtherObject;}` where `myOtherObject` is some object you've created just like you created your `test` variable, except with a different class.

Answer (score 0):

To return an object from Method_A() will look something like this:

```
public Method_A() {
   console.log("Method_A");
   return {
     setSomething: () => {
       console.log('setSomething');
     }
   }
}
```